# Unable to load js file - ChartJS/ChartJS-Node

Tags: node.js, chart.js, commonjs

I've been toying with this all day to no avail so far. I've been using chartjs-node with no issues but I can't even load chartjs-chart-financial.

I've built the library and even used their pre-provided one (https://github.com/vmpowerio/chartjs-node), but whenever I require() the file, it throws errors such as:

Window is not defined
Chart.Ticks is undefined
These errors are on the loading of this file, not even the execution of the function.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong and all my workarounds aren't getting anywhere. I feel like I'm missing something right in front of my face, too.

Comment: Something is wrong with your development environment (Node.js installation, IDE configuration...).

Comment: That's strange. My IDE is Atom so it shouldn't affect it, and my Node.JS is clean installed. Nothing else is having issues.